# how to clear or Empty list box using jquery on dropdown event change

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Can any body help me out how to clear the items in the list box on dropdown event change.

```
$(function () {
        $("#ddlLevelColumn").change(function () {
            $("#lstCodelist") ------ I need to clear this listbox1
            $("#lbxSelectedItems")--------------- need to clear list box 2

        });
    });

 <%:Html.ListBox("lstCodelist", Model.CodeListDefaultValue, new { style = "width:99%;height:297px;" })%>
<%:Html.ListBox("lbxSelectedItems", Model.AffectedCodeListboxData, new { style = "width:99%;height:297px;color:blue;" })%>
```

Thanks for your help..

Comment: Please include relevant HTML, not the server side code.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[empty()](http://api.jquery.com/empty/)

```
$("#lstCodelist").empty()
$("#lbxSelectedItems").empty()
```

Answer (score 5):

You can remove all entries (or apply filters as well):

```
$('#listBoxId > option').remove();           // all options
$('#listBoxId > option[val!=""]').remove(); // keep non-empty values
```

That what you're going for? I believe even simpler:

```
$('#listBoxId').empty();
```

Should work as well.

Working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jEWe6/

Answer (score 2):

I think `.empty()` is what you're looking for.

> Remove all child nodes of the set of matched elements from the DOM.

http://api.jquery.com/empty/

Answer (score 1):

You can clear select html elements with something like this:

```
var clear = function() {
  $("#lstCodelist").empty().append('<option value="whatever">Wait for reload</option>');
  $("#lbxSelectedItems").empty().append('<option value="whatever">Wait for reload</option>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also try any of this two approach.

1. `$('#RolesListAvailable').html('');`

OR

2. `$('#RolesListAssigned').empty();`

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
$('#listBoxId').empty();
```